# JavaScript Algorithm for get box placement

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I need to get a position of the box. Currently I'm doing this with IF, ELSE and LOOP. I need to know that, Is there any algorithm for getting the position of the box. I need the solution in JavaScript

**Problem:** If I select one of these numbered box, can I get the 1st, 3rd 9th boxes location? ( example, I select the 3 numbered box, Then I need to get the 9th form selected box. Thats means 0 numbered box.)

Is there any proper Algorithm for this?

[image: Numbers are the locations]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [reminder operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) by taking the actual position and add the offset and apply the remainder operator with the count of boxes.

> The remainder operator returns the remainder left over when one operand is divided by a second operand. It always takes the sign of the dividend.

```js
var actual = 3,
    length = 12,
    offset = 9,
    position = (actual + offset) % length;

console.log(position); // 0
```